# cache misss/ cache miss rate of a 2D array

Tags: c++, performance, caching

I am executing my C++ code on linux. In my code, there is  a large 2D array of some structure. The array is accessed randomly. I have to find how many cache misses occur when that 2D array is accessed. Is there any other solution except valgrind (as it takes too much time to compute results ) that can help me to find cache misses and cache miss rate of this array.

Comment: If the access to the array is encapsulated, maybe write a simple cache simulator for given cache properties and hook it to the array access?

Comment: If it's truly random access, then the hit/miss ratio is just cache_size/array_size.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your program does not just access the 2D array, so memory access includes other variables. It may have some effects, more or less.

If the array access is intensive(or encapsulated), maybe you can use a simple simulator to evaluate the miss rate.

Otherwise, you may need some tools. I suggest Pin, a dynamic binary instrumentation tool, of which the principle is similar to valgrind, while I think the overhead is acceptable, but you have to write the analysis code.

Or a better choice is Vtune, performance analysis tool from intel, try the cache analysis. Still, you need some time to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the cache risks not reproducing the exact same behavior due to minor differences (in replacement policy, protocols, etc..).

A better option is profiling the code - the simplest profiling tool for linux would probably be perf. There's a pretty decent tutorial here - https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

Also see - [Are there any way to profile cache miss in linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394193/are-there-any-way-to-profile-cache-miss-in-linux-kernel) , it includes a list of specific example statistics to check for cache performance